# ng-init with a second json array

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular (currently using 1.4.6).
I am using ng-repeat to iterate through an array of JSON objects. While iterating, I'd like to find a match in a second array, and display some information from both.
Here is a simplified example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="jsCtrl">
customers: <pre>{{customers | json}}</pre>
cars: <pre>{{cars | json}}</pre>

<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-init="car = (cars | filter: {parentid : customer.id})">
    {{customer.id}}. {{customer.name}} |
    {{car.model}}
</div>

</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('jsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        "id" :  1,
        "name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "city" : "Berlin",
        "country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
        "id" :  2,
        "name" : "Steve",
        "city" : "Chicago",
        "country" : "USA"
    }];

    $scope.cars = [{
        "parentid" : 2,
        "make" : "Ford",
        "model" : "Probe",
        "year" : "1990"
    },
    {
        "parentid" : 1,
        "make" : "Acura",
        "model" : "RSX",
        "year" : "2003"
    }];
});
```

Jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/namyzarc/tc0dc5sL/3/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(cars | filter: {parentid : customer.id})` returns an array not object.
Since you will be getting a single result in that array, you can use `{{car[0].model}}` to display the result.

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-init="car = (cars | filter: {parentid : customer.id})">
    {{customer.id}}. {{customer.name}} |
    {{car[0].model}}
</div>
```

But you should really write a function to filter the array and return the result instead of this. Like this:

```
car = filterCars(customer)
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should have a separate controller file which takes care of matching the information between two arrays and pass that particular info to the page you are displaying using ng-bind etc of your choice. That would be a good way to proceed. 
You can use the foreach to loop through the arrays.